# Fatal error in php (exceeded 60s of exec time)

Tags: php, mysql

i wrote a code to update the password encryption in my site..
the code is..

```
<?php
$db= mysql_pconnect("localhost","root","root");
mysql_select_db("nitconnect");
$query="select password from register limit 1000";
$result=mysql_query($query);
$c=0;
while($ans=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $newpass=sha1($ans[0].'Q*iV%qKz$&!C');
    $newone="update register set password='{$newpass}' where password='{$ans[0]}'";
    mysql_query($newone);
}
?>
```

How do i correct this error?

Comment: How many queries are you making? Can you make test `echo` outputs to determine at which point the timeout occurs? Also, add mysql error handling so you can find out whether the script manages to connect to the database. www.php.net/mysql_error

Comment: Could help if you format the code for better visibility (use the code option in the editor) and show the error you're getting.

Comment: "Fatal error in php (**exceeded 60s of exec time**)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is no real solution other than setting php's max_execution_time higher in php.ini but:

mysql natively supports sha1, so maybe you can just do something like

```
update register set password = sha1(concat(password, 'Q*iV%qKz$&!C'))
```

this should be a lot quicker than your php solution.

still the performance of your query looks very low unless you are on an ancient box. maybe you have no index defined for the password field?

Comment: thanks.. but my max_execution_time is abt 500secs.. i edited it.. still the error shows up.. any idea abt the error?

Comment: did you restart your webserver? :)

Comment: yup.. btw i queried it directly using ur command in phpmyadmin.. it took jus 0.013 secs.. thanks a lot..!! oh im such a n00b.. :(

Comment: last addition: i hope you change your salt after posting it on the innertubes :)

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php 

  $db= mysql_pconnect("localhost","root","root"); 
  mysql_select_db("nitconnect"); 
  $query="UPDATE register SET password = SHA1(CONCAT(password, 'Q*iV%qKz$&!C')) WHERE 1"; 
  $result=mysql_query($query);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming MySQL's native SHA1 method (as roman suggested) doesn't work, try adding this into your loop:

```
set_time_limit(10);
```

It basically will reset the PHP timeout everytime that function is called, giving it 10 more seconds to complete.

Answer (score 0):

You are selecting 1000 records and then using each value in foreach loop and updating the db again, this is probably what makes you out of the time, try increasing the time limit by putting this on top of your script:

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 14000); // or whatever value
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be to do records in chunks, then use a header to send yourself back to the same script, passing the last updated record's index, and then do the next chunk.

Something like:

```
if(issset($_GET['start']) {
   $start = $_GET['start'];
} else {
   $start = 0;
}

$query="select password from register limit $start, 50";
... do your stuff ...

$start = $start + 50;
header("Location: http://www.example.com/yourscript.php?start=$start");
```